# SQL Select rows where all rows from linked table have the same value in column x

Tags: sql

I have 3 tables...

- Inspection (A)
- Inspection_Vehicle (B)
- Inspection_Vehicle_Defect (C)

I want to return all rows from A when all linked rows from C have the a value of **6** in column *Checklist_Result_ID*

Table C contains a column that's linked to table B - Inspection_Vehicle_ID.
Table B contains a column that's linked to table A - Inspection_ID.

I want to do something like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT A.* FROM Inspection AS A
LEFT JOIN Inspection_Vehicle AS B ON B.Inspection_ID = A.Inspection_ID
LEFT JOIN Inspection_Vehicle_Defect AS C ON C.Inspection_Vehicle_ID = B.Inspection_Vehicle_ID
WHERE C.Checklist_Result_ID = 6;
```

Except that I only want results when **ALL** the linked rows in C have C.Checklist_Result_ID=6.

For example, when table C has the following rows:

```
ID    Inspection_Vehicle_ID   Checklist_Result_ID
5     1001                    6
6     1001                    6
7     1001                    6
8     1001                    5
```

...Then, I **don't** want any rows from A when *A.Inspection_ID* = *B.Inspection_ID* AND *B.Inspection_Vehicle_ID* = 1001

But if C.Checklist_Result_ID = 6 in all linked rows from C, I want those records.

Comment: What if there are no linked rows?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would approach this as:

```
SELECT i.*
FROM Inspection i JOIN
     (SELECT iv.Inspection_ID
      FROM Inspection_Vehicle iv JOIN
           Inspection_Vehicle_Defect ivd
           ON ivd.Inspection_Vehicle_ID = iv.Inspection_Vehicle_ID
      GROUP BY iv.Inspection_ID
      HAVING COUNT(*) = SUM(CASE WHEN ivd.Checklist_Result_ID = 6 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
     ) ivd
     ON ivd.Inspection_ID = i.Inspection_ID;
```

This makes a point of removing the `SELECT DISTINCT` -- a performance killer.

Comment: I'm getting an empty result set with this query.

Comment: @Julian . . . I fixed the query.

Answer (score 0):

You need a double-negative to do what you need, I've just done the 'B->C' relationship for speed:

```
Select  * 
from    B 
where   B.ID NOT in 
(
    Select  * 
    from    C 
    where   checklist_result_id <> 6 
    and     c.id = b.id
)
```

This will give you B if linked rows in C have no value other than '6', but will also return B if there are no linked rows in C.

If that's wrong, you will need to also do

```
Select  * 
from    B 
where   B.ID NOT in 
(
    Select  ID 
    from    C 
    where   checklist_result_id <> 6 
    and     c.id = b.id
) 
and     B.ID in 
(
    Select  ID 
    from    C 
    where   c.id = b.id
)
```